# How to find rectangle in black region opencv (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm newbie OpenCV. I am using opencv for find position attach a stamp in image. The stamp can't overlap with other object in image.

Example binary image with white region is object on image, black region is none object
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQdmi.png)

Result : Find rect in black region (in white circle) can attach stamp
[Result imagge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otX76.png)

Please help me find rect in black region same blue rect.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you know about rectangles count then it can use kmeans for clusterization points.
First get only blue points and binarization they:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("NQdmi.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

std::vector<cv::Mat> chans;
cv::split(img, chans);

cv::Mat diff;
cv::absdiff(chans[2], chans[1], diff);

cv::threshold(diff, diff, 1, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

cv::imshow("diff", diff);
```

Only blue points:

[image: Binarization result]

Clusterization points and find rotated rectangles:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
for (int y = 0; y < diff.rows; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < diff.cols; ++x)
    {
        if (diff.at<uchar>(y, x))
        {
            points.emplace_back(x, y);
        }
    }
}

cv::Mat pointsKmeans(points.size(), 1, CV_32FC2, &points[0]);
cv::Mat labels;
int clusterCount = 2;
cv::Mat centers;

cv::kmeans(pointsKmeans, clusterCount, labels,
    cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS+cv::TermCriteria::COUNT, 100, 1.0),
       3, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> points1;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points2;

cv::Mat draw = img.clone();
for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
{
    int clusterIdx = labels.at<int>(i);
    if (clusterIdx > 0)
    {
        cv::circle(draw, points[i], 2, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), cv::FILLED, cv::LINE_AA);
        points1.push_back(points[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        cv::circle(draw, points[i], 2, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), cv::FILLED, cv::LINE_AA);
        points2.push_back(points[i]);
    }
}

auto DrawRRect = [draw](const std::vector<cv::Point2f>& pp)
{
    cv::RotatedRect rr = cv::minAreaRect(pp);
    cv::Point2f corners[4];
    rr.points(corners);
    cv::line(draw, corners[0], corners[1], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    cv::line(draw, corners[1], corners[2], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    cv::line(draw, corners[2], corners[3], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    cv::line(draw, corners[3], corners[0], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
};
DrawRRect(points1);
DrawRRect(points2);

cv::imshow("draw", draw);
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi Nuzhny! Thanks for your answer. But I mean, binary image only black region and white region (not blue rectangle). We must find max rectangle on black region. Image have blue rectangle is an example after find rectangle in black region.